# How to return as a list only numbers from a command output in Jenkinsfile/Groovy?

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We need to return as an option on this Jenkinsfile only the revision number from our k8s applications, but the command returns the entire output, and all my regex and escapes on the command was not working on it. Here is the code:

```
                    choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
                    description: 'Revision of the application on kubernetes', 
                    name: 'revision', 
                    omitValueField: false, 
                    randomName: 'choice-parameter-5633384460832177', 
                    referencedParameters: 'namespaces,deployment', 
                    script: [
                        $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                        script: [
                            classpath: [],
                            sandbox: true,
                            script: """
                                if (namespaces.equals("Select")){
                                    return["Nothing to do - Select your deployment"]
                                } else {
                                    def revResult = null
                                    def kubecmd0 = "kubectl rollout history deploy --kubeconfig=${kubefilePrd} -n " + namespaces + " " + deployment + " "
                                    def kubecmd1 = kubecmd0.execute().in.text.split().toList()
                                    return kubecmd1

                                }
                            """

                        ]
```

On Jenkins's job:

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfNq9.png)

Is there any function or magic regex that could solve this?

Comment: Could you show what you want to extract and from which result?

Comment: My command returns something like this: 

```deployment.extensions/workflow
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
65        kubectl apply --kubeconfig=/var/jenkins_home/kubeconfig/prd-config --record=true --filename=k8s --namespace=zcc
66        kubectl apply --kubeconfig=/var/jenkins_home/kubeconfig/prd-config --record=true --filename=k8s --namespace=zcc
67        kubectl apply --kubeconfig=/var/jenkins_home/kubeconfig/prd-config --record=true --filename=k8s --namespace=zcc
```

I need only the first column (number 65, 66 and 67). On bash I can do it with awk, but I need in groovy in this case.

Comment: please edit your question and add formatted information there.

Comment: btw. you could output only required columns from `kubectl`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#output-options

Comment: I agree this would be easier to filter with `kubectl` Go filters and not within the the Groovy.

Comment: And do you have any tip or sample of this command? Because I'm trying here, and the rollout history command using the -o json and others doesn't capture the information that I need

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/72782

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
[$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
    choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
    description: 'Revision of the application on kubernetes', 
    name: 'revision', 
    randomName: 'choice-parameter-5633384460832177', 
    referencedParameters: 'namespaces,deployment', 
    script: [
        $class: 'GroovyScript', 
        script: [
            classpath: [],
            sandbox: true,
            script: """
                if (namespaces.equals("Select")){
                    return["Nothing to do - Select your deployment"]
                } else {
                    def command = "kubectl rollout history deploy --kubeconfig=${kubefilePrd} -n " + namespaces + " " + deployment  + "| grep -v REVISION | grep -v deployment | cut -f1 -d' '"
                    def output = ['bash', '-c', command].execute().in.text
                    return output.split().toList()

                }
            """

        ]
```

Basically, it's necessary to call a bash, and not use groovy directly. Works for me. :)